# How to rewrite part of url in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My url looks like

```
http://example.com/picture.php/82-1/category/19-appenzell_ausserrhoden?map
```

I want this to be re-written as

```
http://example.com/picture/82-1/category/19-appenzell_ausserrhoden?map
```

How can I do it in HTaccess?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
RewriteRule    ^picture/?$ picture.php [NC,L] #flags: case insensitive, last
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^picture/(.+)$ picture.php/$1 [NC,L]
```